# Overleaf: Package pdftex.def error: File '...' not found: using draft setting

Tags: graphics, epstopdf

Because the answers to similar questions do not seem to work for my case, I post my question here:

I am currently writing an article in overleaf for which I use the latex template of my university. All .tex files are stored in a folder called 'mainFolder', which also contains another subfolder called 'Images' in which I store all the images I use. I am trying to load a .eps file into a figure as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mainFolder/Images/image1.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mainFolder/Images/image2.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\caption[]{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, I always get the error: "Package pdftex.def error file not found using draft setting". Minimal working examples with the same structure also work for me, so I do not know where I go wrong.

My included packages are:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./mainFolder/Images/]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

Adding '[outdir=./mainFolder/Images/]' to the epstopdf package inclusion was proposed as a fix to similar questions, but does not work here. Neither does leaving it out, or changing it to './' or './mainFolder/'.

I was wondering if anybody had encountered the same problem, or knows how to find out where the error comes from in this particular case. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you would be better to use pdf files rather than eps, eps requies calling epstopdf  to  covert the files to pdf using restricted shell-escape.  using draft mode prevents teh file being loaded I'm not  sure that works woth epstopdf transformation. the fact that overleaf uses output directory commandline option adds to the cpmplication.

Comment: also why not load all the files into the main directory? You don't have to have a deep directory structure if it complicates things.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your reply. First off, I use eps files because I want to convert a figure in Matlab to latex, but I want to scale the images such that the fontsize in these figures matches the latex font. Apparently, eps files stored with the correct number of points in matlab should do the trick. The reason why I do not load all the files in the main directory is because there is another folder with template examples which I keep in the same directory such that I can have a quick look every once and a while.

Comment: matlab can save the images as pdf surely? Given that pdftex can not include eps there is a high overhead and little gain from using eps as they have to be converted to pdf anyway before being used.

Comment: I thought the disadvantage of saving as pdf is that you already fix your text in a certain fontsize, such that if you need to resize your image for whatever reason, you would have to make an entirely new figure in Matlab first. Using eps on the other hand creates points which can then dynamically be adjusted in latex itself, leading to less overhead in the end after all.

Comment: No, pdflatex can not include eps files so all you are doing is forcing it to call out to epstopdf to convert the eps into pdf to be included.

Comment: @IHBPP You probably think of psfrag?